# Usar Camera ^0.10.5+2 con Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

Tengo un problema al querer usar el paquete de cámara con el gestor de estados Flutter Bloc. Actualmente mi Bloc se encarga de 2 cosas, tomar una fotografía y usar el reconocimiento facial para validar que exista un rostro, pero tengo un problema al "Cancelar la captura de la foto" presionando el leading button de mi appbar, ya que al volver atrás la cámara me marca este error:

[image: Evidencia visual]

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building CameraPreview:
A CameraController was used after being disposed.

Once you have called dispose() on a CameraController, it can no longer be used.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CameraPreview CameraPreview:file:///D:/Projects/pruebas/auth/lib/gestor_checador/presentation/views/autocheck/autocheck_view.dart:63:28
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:179:9)
#1      ChangeNotifier.debugAssertNotDisposed (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:186:6)
#2      ChangeNotifier.addListener (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:238:27)
#3      _ValueListenableBuilderState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/value_listenable_builder.dart:161:28)
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5219:55)
#5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5062:5)
...     Normal element mounting (19 frames)
#24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
#25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3702:20)
#26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
#27     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5251:11)
#28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
#29     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
#30     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
#31     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#32     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#33     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#34     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#35     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#36     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#37     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
==================================================================================================
```

Esto me está causando problemas ya que mi revisando la documentación del paquete me muestra esta información relevante:

> Handling Lifecycle states  As of version 0.5.0 of the camera plugin,
> lifecycle changes are no longer handled by the plugin. This means
> developers are now responsible to control camera resources when the
> lifecycle state is updated. Failure to do so might lead to unexpected
> behavior (for example as described in issue #39109). Handling
> lifecycle changes can be done by overriding the
> didChangeAppLifecycleState method like so:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  final CameraController? cameraController = controller;

  // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
  if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    cameraController.dispose();
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _initializeCameraController(cameraController.description);
  }
}
```

el problema está en que realmente no se como utilizarlo para que me corrija el error, tengo entendido que es porque uso el dispose, pero lo agregé especialmente porque al no usarlo me marca que hay 2 cámaras activas. Esto es gracias a que uso la lectura de QR de mobile_scanner, tengo entendido que ese paquete si cierra todo después de usarse, pero esa individualmente no me marca ningún error.

Este es mi código del bloc:

camera_bloc.dart

```
// Packages
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Imports
import 'package:google_mlkit_face_detection/google_mlkit_face_detection.dart';

part 'camera_event.dart';

part 'camera_state.dart';

class CameraBloc extends Bloc<CameraEvent, CameraState> {
  // Variables
  CameraController? controller;
  Future<void>? initializeControllerFuture;
  final faceDetector = FaceDetector(options: FaceDetectorOptions());

  CameraBloc() : super(const CameraState()) {
    // Action: Initialize Camera when the bloc is created
    _initializeCamera();

    // Event: Take a photo
    on<TakePicture>((event, emit) async {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: PhotoStatus.takingPhoto));
      try {
        await initializeControllerFuture;
        final image = await controller!.takePicture();

        // Action: Detect all faces in the image
        final faces = await faceDetector
            .processImage(InputImage.fromFilePath(image.path));

        // Condition: Is there any face in the image?
        if (faces.isEmpty) {
          emit(state.copyWith(imagePath: image.path, status: PhotoStatus.failure));
          return;
        }

        emit(state.copyWith(imagePath: image.path, status: PhotoStatus.loaded));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(state.copyWith(status: PhotoStatus.failure));
      }
    });

    // Event: Initialize Camera View
    on<InitCameraView>((event, emit) async {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: PhotoStatus.loaded));
    });
  }

  // Method: Initialize Camera Controller
  Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
    controller?.dispose();
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final frontCamera = cameras.firstWhere(
      (camera) => camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.front,
    );

    controller = CameraController(
      frontCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    initializeControllerFuture = controller!.initialize();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(AppLifecycleObserver(this));
    add(InitCameraView());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await super.close();
    await controller?.dispose();
  }
}

class AppLifecycleObserver extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final CameraBloc cameraBloc;

  AppLifecycleObserver(this.cameraBloc);

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      if (cameraBloc.controller != null && cameraBloc.controller!.value.isInitialized) {
        cameraBloc.controller!.stopImageStream();
      }
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (cameraBloc.controller != null && cameraBloc.controller!.value.isInitialized) {
        cameraBloc.controller!.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
          // Process the camera frames
          // ...
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

camera_event.dart

```
part of 'camera_bloc.dart';

abstract class CameraEvent extends Equatable {
  const CameraEvent();
}

class TakePicture extends CameraEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class InitCameraView extends CameraEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

camera_state.dart

```
part of 'camera_bloc.dart';

enum PhotoStatus { initial, loaded, takingPhoto, failure }

class CameraState extends Equatable {
  // Constructor
  const CameraState({
    this.status = PhotoStatus.initial,
    this.imagePath = '',
  });

  // Attributes
  final PhotoStatus status;
  final String imagePath;

  @override
  // Method:
  List<Object?> get props => [status, imagePath];

  // Method: CopyWith
  CameraState copyWith({
    PhotoStatus? status,
    String? imagePath,
  }) =>
      CameraState(
        status: status ?? this.status,
        imagePath: imagePath ?? this.imagePath,
      );
}
```

Y esta es mi pantalla que dibuja la UI:

```
class AutoCheckScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Constructor
  const AutoCheckScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FacialRecognition(
      onBackButtonPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const CheckerScreen(),
          ),
          (route) => false),
    );
  }
}

class FacialRecognition extends StatelessWidget {
  // Constructor
  const FacialRecognition({
    super.key,
    this.onBackButtonPressed,
  });

  // Attributes
  final Function? onBackButtonPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Variable
    final cameraBloc = context.read<CameraBloc>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Take a picture'),
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            cameraBloc.close();
            onBackButtonPressed!() ?? Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CameraBloc, CameraState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == PhotoStatus.loaded) {
          return FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: cameraBloc.initializeControllerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // Condition: Is the Future complete?
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // * Yes => Display the preview
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    child: CameraPreview(cameraBloc.controller!),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                // * No => Display a loading indicator until the controller is initialized
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          );
        }

        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: const PhotoButton(),
    );
  }
}
```

Y por último el botón que manda la foto:

```
class PhotoButton extends StatelessWidget {
  // Constructor
  const PhotoButton({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Variable
    final cameraBloc = context.read<CameraBloc>();

    return FloatingActionButton.large(
      onPressed: () async {
        // Action: Take a picture
        cameraBloc.add(TakePicture());

        // Action: Navigate to the preview screen
        await Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const PhotoPreviewScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.camera),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias volver a iniciar `CameraController` después de hacer pop hacia el parent widget. En tu app bar, en el leading button que es el que se encarga de volver al parent widget, usa este código:

`Navigator.of(context).then(() => controller.start())`

En controller.start() llama a la función necesaria para volver a inicializar la cámara.